# Number of solutions to linear equation $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=m$ when the domain of $x_i\ne$ domain of $x_j$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, integer-partitions

In the lecture notes of one of my previous classes, it was used that if we have an equation of the form
$$\tag{1}
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=m
$$
then the total number of solutions, when each $x_i$ is a non-negative integer, can be written
$$\tag{2}
C(m+n-1, m)=\frac{(m+n-1) !}{(n-1) ! \cdot m !}
$$
so that, for example,
$$\tag{3}
x_1+x_2+x_3=14,\qquad x_{1,2,3}\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}
$$
has $C(14+3-1,14)=120$ solutions. However, what if each $x_i$ is restricted to a different subset of the positive integers? For example, if we in eq. $(3)$ need $x_1>1$,  $x_2>0 $, and $x_3>3$, is there a formula to determine the total number of solutions?

Comment: You have 14 identical cookies. How many ways are there to distribute all the cookies to Alice, Bob, and Carol, so that Alice receives more than 1 cookie, Bob receives more than 0 cookies, and Carol receives more than 3 cookies? One you give everyone their required number of cookies, the remaining cookies can be distributed using the usual $x_1+x_2+x_3=m$ scheme, where all variables are nonnegative integers, and $m$ is the number of cookies remaining.

Comment: Ah, yes. So I just get a new equation $\tilde{x_1}+\tilde{x_2}+\tilde{x_3}=7$ and can use eq. $(2)$.

Comment: More generally, there are methods using *generating functions*, and methods using *inclusion-exclusion*.